# How to access a dataclass docstring and comments

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

How to access a dataclass docstring and comments:

E.g. for the following dataclass:

```
@dataclass
class MyDataClass:
    # an integer
    i: int  

    s: str # inline comment
    """ a string """
```

I would like an API like

```
>>> print(MyDataClass.DOC().i)
an integer
```

Note: a related python [enhancement request](https://bugs.python.org/issue38401) was rejected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a single line to the dataclass definition

```
@dataclass
class MyDataClass:
    ...
    DOC = classmethod(get_dataclass_attributes_doc)
```

where `get_dataclass_attributes_doc` is implemented below using `simple_parsing.docstring` and `Munch`

```
from simple_parsing.docstring import get_attribute_docstring, AttributeDocString
from typing import get_type_hints
from munch import Munch
from dataclasses import asdict

def get_dataclass_attributes_doc(some_dataclass):
    def get_attribute_unified_doc(some_dataclass, key):
        """ returns a string that chains the above-comment, inline-comment and docstring """
        all_docstrings: AttributeDocString = get_attribute_docstring(some_dataclass, key)
        doc_list = asdict(all_docstrings).values()
        return '\n'.join(doc_list)
 
    attribute_docs = Munch()
    for key in get_type_hints(some_dataclass).keys():
        attribute_docs[key] = get_attribute_unified_doc(some_dataclass, key)
    return attribute_docs
```

Comment: not sure why `Munch` is needed (could be `attribute_docs = {}`)